# JSP with Spring form not calling Spring 4.x controller

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc, controller

I am a Spring newbie and have a simple form on a JSP:

```
    <!-- Register Person. -->        
    <p>To register with the library, please <i>click</i> the button below:</p>
    <c:url value="/registerPerson/register" var="url" />
    <form:form commandName="person" action="${url}" method="get">   
        <input type="submit" value="Register">                
    </form:form>
```

Which I want to use to talk to a Spring controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registerPerson")
@SessionAttributes("person")
public class RegisterPersonController {

private RegisterPersonValidator registerPersonValidator;
private PersonService personService;

@Autowired
public RegisterPersonController(RegisterPersonValidator registerPersonValidator,    PersonService personService) {
    this.registerPersonValidator = registerPersonValidator;
    this.personService = personService;
}

// Populates registerPersonForm with a dummy Person when a new Person is registering with the Library.
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getRegisterPerson(Model model) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    Person person = new Person();
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    return "registerPerson";
}
```

But when I try the form, I simply get a Tomcat 404 page not found error.

The `registerPerson` view is stored in `\web\WEB-INF\jsp` as a JSP.

My `Dispatcherservlet` is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven />    
<context:component-scan base-package="library.controller" />    
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And `web.xml`:

```
<display-name>Library</display-name>                 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>library</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>library</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>        
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>                   
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Can anyone advise why the controller is not called when I try URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/Library/registerPerson
```

Using GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Library to library, urls are mapped to servlet name, not display name.

You have no controller for this url

```
 <c:url value="/registerPerson/register" var="url" />
```

You have shown only "/registerPerson".

Comment: Adding @RequestMapping("/register")
@SessionAttributes("person") to the method in the controller has no effect.

Comment: @MrMorgan You need to change to lowercase library to get the initial form

Comment: <form id="person" action="/library/registerPerson/register" method="get">    in the form gives me a blank page.

Comment: @MrMorgan "/library/registerPerson" should work, however you will need an additional *post* controller method for "/library/registerPerson/register"

Comment: post method is in the controller already. I still get either a blank page or 404.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no stacktrace. and I'm not logging at the moment.

Comment: You said you either get blank page or 404, this is impossible its one of the other, what exactly have you tried ? My answer should work, if you have tried this and it doesn't work, please get your logging working and post the stacktrace.

Comment: I have tried changing the URLs and so on. But all I get now is a blank page when I should see an form. GEtting logging working will take some time.

Comment: So you get a blank page, whereas before you got a 404 ? Then your jsp isn't rendering as you expect. And your original problem is solved. If you need help getting logging working, post a question.

Comment: I get a blank page with either.

Comment: with either what ? Its not clear at all what your current error is an what java code caused it.

Comment: the JSP doesn't appear to be calling the controller and I am simply getting a blank page because the mapping doesn't work for some reason.

there's not much more I can say.

Comment: I'll try again. You get a blank page, whereas before you got a 404 ? You need to get your logging sorted. You can't build anythgn without logging problems.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. If I try http://localhost:8080/Library/registerPerson/register? I get 404. With lower case l for Library, I get a blank page.

Server log simply reports: Jun 09, 2014 4:15:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'library'

Comment: any advice would be welcome. I have to leave this now anyway.

Comment: Right, that won't work becuase you are using a GET request to access a method/requestmapping that requires a POST action type. If you try  "localhost:8080/library/registerPerson", you should get the original form, which then needs to call the post method, whcih you have now created.

Comment: I am using a GET request from one JSP in order to call the GET method of the controller. This is because I want the controller to display the form in an initial blank state on the second JSP. Only when the form is populated would I expect to call the POST method of the controller and have it validate the user's input.

Comment: Solution posted as part of question.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*

Code above changed thus. JSP form has been changed to:

```
    <p>To register with the library, please <i>click</i> the button below:</p>
    <c:url value="/registerPerson/register" var="registerURL" />
    <form:form action="${registerURL}" method="get">   
        <input type="submit" value="Register">                
    </form:form>
```

And the controller to:

```
private RegisterPersonValidator registerPersonValidator;    
private PersonService personService;

@Autowired
public RegisterPersonController(RegisterPersonValidator registerPersonValidator, PersonService personService) {
    this.registerPersonValidator = registerPersonValidator;
    this.personService = personService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getRegisterPerson(Model model) {        
    Person person = new Person();        
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    return "registerPerson";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/register")
public String postRegisterPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, 
                                 BindingResult bindingResult, 
                                 SessionStatus sessionStatus, Model model) {    
    System.out.println(person.toString());
    registerPersonValidator.validate(person, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registerPerson";
    }
    else {
        int id = personService.insert(person);
        sessionStatus.setComplete();
        return "personOptions/id/" + id;
    }
}
```

And it appears to work now.